# Is there any dependency injection framework for Windows Store App?

Tags: angularjs, winjs

Is there any dependency injection framework for Windows Store App?
I used AngularJS in my previous web project, it has functions like DI, view management, data binding.

I'm developing Windows Store App now. The built-in WinJS and Angular have a lot in common, such as view management, data binding. But I don't know if WinJS supports DI or not.

BTW, is there any mocking/unit testing framework for WinJS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about AngularJS, but we ported an application that was using KnockoutJS and RequireJS fairly easily just using them in conjunction with the WinJS framework.  You may be able to use Angular in conjunction with WinJS and continue to use all of Angular's DI features that you desire.

On the unit testing front, we used a fork of QUnit ([QUnitMetro](http://qunitmetro.github.io/QUnitMetro/)) with our application and had a lot of success with it.

Comment: The reason I must only use one because WinJS and AngularJS conflict when changing views. WinJS uses PageControl and AngularJS uses route. I prefer to use PageControl because WinJS has built-in animation. But I'm afraid that WinJS does not have DI.